# Core Data migration error 134100

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I am trying to migrate my current core data structure to a new data structure however I am continually getting the same error no matter what I do:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Open Failed', reason: 'Reason: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)'
```

According to the documentation this means: NSPersistentStoreIncompatibleVersionHashError

I cannot just erase the app from the simulator as it has already gone out to the app store.

The persistent store coordinator in the app delegate is as follows:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{

if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {

    return persistentStoreCoordinator;

}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"DATABASELOC.sqlite"];

NSLog(@"URL: %@", storeURL);

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,

                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

NSError *error = nil;

persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {

    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    abort();

}

return persistentStoreCoordinator;


}
```

And my managedobjectmodel within the app delegate is as follows:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{

if (managedObjectModel != nil) {

    return managedObjectModel;

}

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DATABASELOC" ofType:@"momd"];

NSURL *momURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:momURL];

return managedObjectModel;


}
```

I have generated a second model version, and updated the current version, and if I choose either as the current, if it is the same as the original model it loads fine. However as soon as I make a minor change the model that is current the same error comes up.

I guess it appears that it is not recognizing that there is a new model, but no matter what I do I cannot get past this error.

Has anyone else had this problem? Can anyone offer some advice?

Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Once you make a change to the model you will have to release a new version in order for the automatic versioning to take effect. This looks to be the case where switching between the versions is working fine, however once you alter a version it crashes because it does not know how to update since it is not a new version.

Comment: Ok, when you say release a new version, do you mean the targets version or the models version no?

Comment: I changed the models as follows: Set the old model's identifier to 1; Set the new model's identifier to 2; Set the new model as the current model; Increased the target version & build numbers

I'm still getting the same error message. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that is what i meant, do you have the automatic version updating code also when your running the app?

Comment: return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@YES, NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, @YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm passing the NSDictionary with those options to the persistentStoreCoordinator in the addPersistentStoreWithType method. But where would I need to return the dictionary?

Comment: the return was just because i had it in a method sorry about that